# How to print Exact data from URL

Tags: python, url, urllib

Using Python how can I print `request_token` from a URL like:

```
https://kite.trade/?request_token=p87tOTSXRSp4O20TGr870n2JiXFKISIh&action=login&status=success
```

IE: the text between `=` to `&` following `request_token`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `parse_qs` from `urllib.parse`.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs #import stuff

#parse the url
url_obj = urlparse('https://kite.trade/?request_token=p87tOTSXRSp4O20TGr870n2JiXFKISIh&action=login&status=success')
#get a dictionary from the query
q_dict = parse_qs(url_obj.query)
#now get query args by key name. 
print(q_dict["request_token"])
print(q_dict["status"])
```

[Here is a link to the documentation for `parse_qs`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs)

Answer (score 0):

Use the urlparse library in python 2 https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

Or urllib.parse in python 3
https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use split the strings using string functions and put the query into a dict like:

#### Code:

```
url = 'https://kite.trade/?request_token=p87tOTSXRSp4O20TGr870n2JiXFKISIh&' \
      'action=login&status=success'

query = dict(a.split('=') for a in url.split('?')[1].split('&'))
print(query)
```

You can do the same using the urllib like:

```
import urllib
query = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).query)
print(query['request_token'][0])
```

#### Results:

```
{'request_token': 'p87tOTSXRSp4O20TGr870n2JiXFKISIh', 'action': 'login', 'status': 'success'}
p87tOTSXRSp4O20TGr870n2JiXFKISIh
```

Comment: @KiranKumarReddy, you are very welcome.  However, on SO the very best way to say thanks is to upvote *any* questions or answers you find useful.  And on your questions, if one of the answers is a good fit for your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer.  See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for guidelines.